# JavaScript compiler requires '===' instead of '==' everywhere in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and try to update all updates which it needs.

My problem: when I create a new js file, the js compiler would gave me an error `eqeqeq` (I don't understand what this code means) whenever I use `'=='` to compare.

Example:

```
// Declaring a number within a default value
var caret_index = 0;

// Now, js compiler should know 'caret_index' type
// alert(typeof(caret_index)); -> number
// alert($.type(caret_index)); -> number

// So,

// Expected '===' and instead of saw '=='
if (caret_index == 0) {
   // ...
}
```

[image: 1]

That said: `You must use '===' in the`if`condition.`

Why? It just needn't cast `caret_index` to `number` before comparing to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Visual Studio, it's your lint settings. If you don't have a `.eslintrc.json` file in your project root, then create it.  Visual Studio will read this to see which rules it should apply.  Look for the triple equals rule:

```
    "triple-equals": [
        false,
        "allow-null-check"
    ]
```

alternatively, it might be a rule contained in an external file if you have any references under rules directory:

```
"rulesDirectory" :[]
```

Comment: Tslint is for typescript, the file you are looking for here is eslintrc.json, which should be at the root directory of your project.

Comment: Yes, apologies, I didn't even notice the .js extension.  You're correct, i'll remove this answer in a minute

Comment: Don't remove it, just edit it with the right file ;)

Comment: Done!  I'm working on a TS project at the moment, which has obviously got me thinking about everything using TS-logic.  Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @Melvin: Isn't there somewhere central you can put one so you don't have to have it per-project if you don't want to?

Comment: I'm using mvc 5 and try to find the file `eslintrc.json` in the folder `Scripts`, but no result was found. So, should I create new and put it in folder `Script`?

Comment: @HappyCoding - usually you'll put it in the root of your .NET project, along with web.config, etc

Comment: @HappyCoding: Note that the answer says the filename is `.eslintrc.json`, not `eslintrc.json`.